# Where Can I get the Tweet Button as a png?

Tags: apache-flex, twitter

I'm putting a "tweet this" button on a Flex 3 site and I need to embed the artwork. Where can I find Twitter's [tweet button](http://twitter.com/goodies/tweetbutton)  as a png with a transparent background, instead of linking to it? (As I'm using Flex, I won't be able to set it up as they've shown. I know how to set-up the code, but I need the tweet icon). Can anyone recommend a place to download it? It can be a jpg or gif, whatever.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: why you cannot download it from the link you posted in your question?

Comment: Thanks Igor, That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50+ free 'Tweet This' buttons -

http://www.bloggersentral.com/2009/06/50-free-tweet-this-buttons.html

and here is a link to 100+ -

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/100-remarkably-beautiful-twitter-icons-and-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1600&bih=715&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=tweet+this+button+png&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=